# Awaiting doesn't appear to be waiting for results in my functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I realize this sort of question has been asked here, and I have done extensive research before I posted this question.

I have seven operations that need to be run in order. Most are database related, so they may take some time to finish up.

1. getLiveItems =>  puppeteer page  (avg 10 seconds)
2. getOldItems  =>  mySQL query
3. getNewItems  =>  mySQL query
4. compareItems => lodash compare
5. saveOldItems =>  mySQL insert query
6. saveNewItems =>  mySQL insert query
7. notifyUser => puppeteer open page

I understand I need to either use a callback, or a promise. But I can't even get past the first two operations using either method.

Here is my latest attempt.

```
var oldItems, newItems;


var getoldItems = async function(callback) {
    await connection.query('SELECT * FROM items', function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else 
            callback(null, rows);
    });
}

var getnewItems = async function(callback) {
    await connection.query('SELECT * FROM newItems', function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else 
            callback(null, rows);
    });
}



const init = async function(){

    await getoldItems(function(err, content) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);

        } else {
            oldItems = content;
            return oldItems;
        }
    })

    await getnewItems(function(err, content) {
        if(err){
           // console.log(err);  
        } else {
            newItems = content;
            return newItems;
        }
    })

    return;

}

( async function() {
 await init();
 console.log(oldItems);
 console.log(newItems);   
});
```

I get no output. No errors, either.

I'm really confused. I have read, and read about this topic, but I am missing something fundamental.

This is how my mind is processing my script , thus the reason I wrote it that way...

> I am going to await the results from the init function, which does the
>   following...
>
> I am going to wait for the results of getOldItems and then move on
>   to waiting for the results of getNewItems. Then, I am going to return
>   back to Init and console out both results.

**What Am I Missing?!**

Thank you in advance.

Frustrated In Florida,
John

Comment: you're using callbacks, not Promises there, so your awaits aren't actually doing anything there.  I'm just guessing here, are you using the mysql npm package?  You have a few choices:  switch to all callbacks, wrap your callbacks with Promises, use a db library that supports Promises natively

Comment: yes I am using the mysql package. If I am using promises, albeit news to me, lol, I need to resolve something somewhere then, don't I?

Comment: As has already been said, `await` only does something useful if you `await` a promise.  Your version of mysql does not do promises so you can't use `await` with it directly.  I would suggest switching to [mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) which has promise support built in as shown [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-promise-wrapper).  You can then NOT pass a callback and it will return a promise which you can use with `await` to get the result that way.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! MySql2. Thanks for the advice. If you can post as an answer, I will accept as that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using callbacks, not Promises, so your awaits aren't actually doing anything.
You have a few choices:
 - switch to all callbacks
 - wrap your callbacks with Promises
 - use a db library that supports Promises natively

A few Promise-enabled mysql libraries:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql